# Source code control with TradingView and Pine

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm searching for a source code control system for TradingView and Pine.

Seems obvious that one does not exist within in TradingView itself, but curious of any of you ingenious developers have devised an external solution.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Every time you save your code, you get a new version number for your code. Later, you can select different versions and see what the code was like in that version. That kinda helps when you need to revert back. Also you can copy different versions into a file and use your favorite text compare tool to see the differences.

[image]

Other than that, I code my indicator step by step to make sure everything is fine and also this way I create new versions for every "step" in my code. It is very common that my indicators have more than 100 versions.